# Build for production script

Tags: git, bash, hook

I'm using EncloseJS to turn my javascript code in executable binary , but I just want to make it into production, for this I created a file `/hooks/build-for-production`, with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
npm install
gulp build
enclose --loglevel info -o ./executable dist/index.js --config config.js
rm !(executable)
```

So, i would like to confirm if the user wants delete everything except the executable file. Something like:

`"Do you want remove everything?"`, and if the user answers is true, delete everything, but if there is uncommited stuffs, just abort.

Is this possible? How check uncommited stuffs??

Also.. i would like to know if what I 'm doing is a good practice, and if it isn't, how should i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git diff --exit-code` which return nonzero if there are any changes:

```
echo -n "Do you want remove everything? (y/n)"
read remove
if [[ $(git diff --exit-code) -eq 0 ]];then
  # have no any uncommitted stuff
else
  # have some uncommitted stuff
  if echo "$remove" | grep -iq "^y";then
    echo "Remove all stuff"
  else
    # do other
  fi
fi
```